Homotopy in $\mathbf{Top}_{\text{Quillen}}$.
Recall the classical model structure $\mathbf{Top}_{\text{Quillen}}$ on the category $\mathbf{Top}$ of (cgwh, if you want) topological spaces. In any model category, there are the notions of (left, right) homotopy, which I shall use and I will refer to the ordinary notion as "topological homotopy" to avoid confusion. I'm interested in the relationships between these four relations.
For an object $X$ in a model category, let me call a factorization $X\sqcup X\rightarrow\mathrm{Cyl}(X)\rightarrow X$ of the codiagonal, in which the second map is a weak equivalence, a cylinder object for $X$. It is called good if the first map is cofibration [this terminology is not standardized]. Two morphisms $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ are left homotopic as soon as there is a cylinder object and a left homotopy $H\colon\mathrm{Cyl}(X)\rightarrow Y$ restricting to $f,g$ along the first map. If two morphisms are left homotopic, there always is a left homotopy defined on a good cylinder object. If $Y$ is fibrant, then there exists a left homotopy defined on any good cylinder object. The case of path space objects and right homotopies is dual. Two maps are homotopic if they are both left and right homotopic.
Now, let's return to $\mathbf{Top}_{\text{Quillen}}$. There is a cylinder object $X\sqcup X\rightarrow X\times I\rightarrow X$ for any top. space $X$. In particular, top. homotopy implies left homotopy. Note that every space is fibrant in this model structure, so if this cylinder object is good, then left homotopy and top. homotopy are the same relation. In the dual scenario, the path space object $Y\rightarrow Y^I\rightarrow Y\times Y$ is always good (and a right homotopy using this path space object is a top. homotopy by currying). Thus, top. homotopy implies right homotopy and, if $X$ is cofibrant, right homotopy and top. homotopy are the same relation. It is easy to see explicitly (using that cofibrations = retracts of relative cellular extensions) that if $X$ is cofibrant, then $X\sqcup X\rightarrow X\times I$ is a cofibration, so in this case, all 4 homotopy relations coincide. In general, top. homotopy implies (left, right) homotopy, yet not every top. space is cofibrant in this model structure, begging the
Question: Are there examples of (left, right) homotopic maps in this model structure that are not topologically homotopic?

Let $\gamma:Top_{Quillen}\rightarrow Ho(Top_{Quillen})$ be the projection to the homotopy category.

Proposition Two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ in $Top_{Quillen}$ are left homotopic if and only if $\gamma(f)=\gamma(g)$.

Proof It's true in any model category that left homotopic morphisms become identified in the homotopy category. Thus we only need to show that $f\simeq_\ell g$ in case $\gamma(f)=\gamma(g)$.
To this end, let $q:\overline X\xrightarrow{\sim} X$ be a cofibrant replacement of $X$ (i.e. $\overline X$ is cofibrant and $q$ is an acylic Serre fibration). Consider the composites $fq,gq:\overline X\rightarrow Y$ and note that $\gamma(fq)=\gamma(q)\gamma(g)=\gamma(g)\gamma(q)=\gamma(gq)$, since we are assuming $\gamma(f)=\gamma(g)$. Since $\overline X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is fibrant, there is a bijection
$$[\overline X,Y]_\ell\cong Ho(Top_{Quillen})(\overline X,Y),$$
where the square brackets denote left homotopy classes of maps. Since $\gamma(fq)=\gamma(gq)$, it follows that $fq\simeq_\ell gq$. Realise this by choosing a `good' cylinder $cyl(\overline X)$ and a map $h:cyl(\overline X)\rightarrow Y$ which makes the following diagram commute
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\overline X\sqcup\overline X @>{q\sqcup q}>> X\sqcup X\\
@V jVV @VV(f,g)V \\
cyl(\overline X) @>{h}>> Y.
\end{CD}$$
The map $j$ in this diagram is supplied by the cylinder and is assumed to be a Serre cofibration. There is also a morphism $cyl(\overline X)\xrightarrow{\sim}\overline X$ supplied by the cylinder which is a weak equivalence. Note that we could assume without loss of generality that $cyl(\overline X)=\overline X\times I$, since $\overline X$ is cofibrant, but this is not necessary.
Now form the pushout diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
\overline X\sqcup\overline X @>{q\sqcup q}>> X\sqcup X\\
@V jVV @VV JV \\
cyl(\overline X) @>R>> Q.
\end{CD}$$
Since $j$ is a Serre cofibration, so is $J$. Moreover, since $q\sqcup q$ is weak equivalence and $Top_{Quillen}$ is a left proper model category, the map $R$ is a weak equivalence. The fold map $X\sqcup X\rightarrow X$ together with the composite
$$cyl(\overline X)\xrightarrow{\sim}\overline X\xrightarrow{\sim}X$$
now induce a map $\theta:R\rightarrow X$. Since both $R$ and the composite above are weak equivalences, so is $\theta$ by the 2-of-3 property. The conclusion is that the triple $(Q,J,\theta)$ is a `good' cylinder on $X$.
Now, the first diagram above induces a map $H:Q\rightarrow Y$ satisfying $QJ=(f,g)$. This $H$ is exactly a left homotopy $f\simeq_\ell g$. $\quad\blacksquare$
Example Let $W$ be any weakly contractible space which is not contractible. To be concrete, we may take $W$ to be the Warsaw circle. Since $W$ is not contractible, the identity $id_W$ is not topologically homotopic to any constant mapping $c:W\rightarrow W$. On the other hand, $\gamma(id_W)=\gamma(c)$, since $W$ is weakly contractible. By the result above, $id_W\simeq_\ell c$.
It's worthwile noting that the cylinder $W\times I$ is not `good'. For instance, in the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
W\sqcup W @>{(id_W,c)}>> W\\
@V jVV @VV V \\
W\times I @>>> \ast
\end{CD}$$
the right-hand map $W\rightarrow\ast$ is an acylic Serre fibration. If $j$ were a Serre cofibration, the square would admit a diagonal, which it does not.
$\quad\square$
Inspection of the proof above above shows that the only input was the fibrancy of $Y$, the fact that $q\sqcup q$ was a weak equivalence, and the left properness of $Top_{Quillen}$. Thus we have the following.

Proposition Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be morphisms in a model category $\mathcal{M}$.

Assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is left proper, every object of $\mathcal{M}$ is fibrant, and that binary copowers of acyclic fibrations with cofibrant domain are weak equivalences. Then $\gamma(f)=\gamma(g)$ if and only if $f\simeq_\ell g$.

Assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is right proper, every object of $\mathcal{M}$ is cofibrant, and that binary powers of acyclic cofibrations with fibrant codomain are weak equivalences. Then $\gamma(f)=\gamma(g)$ if and only if $f\simeq_r g$. $\quad\blacksquare$



As explained above, the criteria of the first bullet point are met by $Top_{Quillen}$. The criteria of the second are met by $sSet_{Kan}$.
It's not difficult to show from here that in the situation of the proposition, $Ho(\mathcal{M})$ is equivalent to the quotient category $\mathcal{M}/\simeq_\ell$ (respectively $\mathcal{M}/\simeq_r$).

Thanks! Now, $\gamma$ also identifies right-homotopic maps, so this implies that right homotopy => left homotopy, hence right homotopy = homotopy. This yields the chain of implications top. homotopy => homotopy = right homotopy => left homotopy. Your example shows that the composite implication cannot be reversed. Do you know if it is also the case that neither of the individual implications can be reversed?
